# How to store the cookie info when android killed my app

Tags: android, session, cookies, web

I have an app need login, I use a singleton http client to do everything, so it can track the cookies for me.

But when I launch a browser intent in my app to view some html pages, the app sometimes be killed by low memory, when user come back from the browser, my app activity would be recreated, but the new http client would not contains that login session id.

So I think what I need is to cache the cookies when my app get killed, and then restore it back when the app got recreated. I know there is a CookieSyncManager, but I do not have a full picture of how to use that.

(1) So How can I do that? is Cookie seralizable, I just thought to cache it in the sdcard, maybe a bad idea.

Another more general question maybe:

(2) How to share httpclient with webview/system browser? Not just pass cookies from httpclient to webiew/browser, but also get the cookies when initialize the cookies, How to make the http client and webview/browser share just *ONE* copy of cookie store in any time?

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences to store cookies as string.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

Also android developers use parcelable class, rather than serializable class. I think the reason is performance issues @ mobile devices...